# Add Element to a form returned by Ajax response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add an element returned by ajax response to a Form ,, so that i can access the value of that element when form is post,,
Any idea how I can do this.

I heard that it could by done through jquery live function ,, but How

Regards,

Comment: What is your ajax request's exact response?

Comment: its an html reponse contain hidden element. I want that hidden element to be the part of my Form

Comment: Did you try $().append or $().html() ?

Comment: Nope, I wonder if the response has the form tag initially, JS will clear this form tag.

Comment: response is simple <input type="hidden" value="" name="field"/>

Comment: Ok, just misunderstand, I wrote the code you are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is your friend:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data) {
     $('form').append(data)
  }
})
```

Comment: My friend, what if there is more than one form? :)

Comment: is changing an id too much hard for a web developer? if someone can't do that, it would be better to forget the ajax.

Comment: Nope, you just must consider it before write that code. Maybe he's new in JS world.

Comment: nope, I say you are not in his class. For you, it is normal, but him... anyway, sorry if I ...

Comment: @EnesUnal [Stack Overflow doesn't know what you are thinking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/183490)

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your form,

```
<form id="myForm" ....>
```

and in function which you fetch ajax response,

```
var data; //which is your responsehtml
...
$("#myForm").html($("#myForm").html() + data);
```